# Blazor FocusOnNavigate sets tabindex=-1

Tags: accessibility, blazor-server-side

I created a Blazor project and in `App.razor` I have this line:

```
<FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="input" />
```

[FocusOnNavigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.focusonnavigate?view=aspnetcore-6.0) sets focus on the first input after navigating. This works fine, but I noticed that with tab you can focus to the next element, but getting the focus back on that element is not possible. This is because the input has `tabindex="-1"` now.

Why is a tabindex added? Is there a way to avoid this?

**Update**: I tried the autofocus attribute on an input without using FocusOnNavigate, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

In [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) doc they said:

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element is not
> reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but could be focused
> with JavaScript or visually by clicking with the mouse. It's mostly
> useful to create accessible widgets with JavaScript.
>
> *Note: A negative value is useful when you have off-screen content that
> appears on a specific event. The user won't be able to focus any
> element with a negative tabindex using the keyboard, but a script can
> do so **by calling the focus() method**.*

and defends on that we can go around that by using `onblure` in your last  `input` and set focus again on your first input:

```
<EditFrom Model=model>

 //Input 1
 <InputText @ref="inputText1"
            class="form-control"
            bind-Value="model.val1"/>

 //Input 2
 <InputText
    class="form-control"
    bind-Value="model.val2"
    @onblure= OnblureHandler/>
</EditForm>

@code{
 puplic class Model
 {
    public string val1 {get; set;}
    public string val2 {get; set;}
 }
 Model model {get; set;}
 InputText inputText1;
 
 private void OnblureHandler()
 {
  if(inputText1.Element.HasValue) 
  {
    inputText1.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I hope there will be a better solution in the future :-) autofocus should just work. But thanks for the help.